# Client to server communication for stopping data streaming

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

Here is my scenario:

1. Server generating endless of data and streaming using WebFlux.
2. Client side developed using WebClient and after meeting certain criteria client want's the server to stop streaming data to avoid further data leakages.

Input stream: Flux.range(1,1000) customer.
Client side: If value is customer is 7 - client doesn't want any more input data. That means server has to stop streaming data.

On the client side I have coded like this:

```java
flux.takeUntil(this::processResponse).subscribe();

private boolean processResponse(Customer customer) {
    boolean foundData = false;
    System.out.println(customer.getCustomer());
    if (customer.getCustomer().equals("customer7")) {
        foundData = true;
    }
    return  foundData;
}
```

I notice that server is still sending the data even though the client doesn't want it anymore.

Comment: It all depends on the communication channel. You're supposed to close the channel once you've got the data.